# BVP Second order ODE Infinite number of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm attempting to solve $X''(x)+ \lambda ^2X=0$ with the boundary conditions:

$X(0)=0$ and $X(L)=0$.

However I do not understand why we have $B_n$

Is this something to do with the linearity of the differential equation? If so please explain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is just an arbitrary constant. Above, in the formula "Now the general solution is ...", it was denoted just by $B$. Below, it turned into $B_n$ to stress that it depends on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [superposition principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) which gives you the solution

> $$ X = \sum_{n} B_n \sin(n\pi x/L). $$